# is there a way to convert conditional formatting to "static" formatting with Google Sheets/Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some Google Sheets with pretty complicated formulas and conditional formatting.

I'm trying to save some archive copies of certain tabs by duplicating them then copying-pasting values. The problem is, all the archive tabs also have conditional formatting, and it's really slowing things down.

Is there a "paste values" version of conditional formatting so that *everything* on the archive tabs is static? I'm trying to speed things up. When I use GAS to copy the formatting, it's copying the *conditional* formatting, so when I do a currentSheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();, all the formatting disappears.

Here's a sample [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1thrAHfMQWRLKM0ZKIQboxCQx7OMj_yd1iyyEIYXQ_N0/edit#gid=1131826256).
All the colors are via conditional formatting. What I would like to do is *delete* all the conditional formatting, but have all the appropriate colors, etc. remain because they are "manually" filled in. That's what I mean by converting the formatting to "static" formatting.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi, please provide a copy/example of the sheets to have some context and also the code you're using. What do you mean by "so that everything on the archive tabs is static "?

Comment: I've added a sample Sheet and clarified my question. I hope this makes it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy the formatting from formatting rules directly, but you can get the individual attributes of the formatting (background, font size, etc) and set them into your destination range. For example, with the set/get functions for background[1][2] and font size[3][4], I used the below code to copy the values for those attributes from one range to another ("A1:AS10" range from 1st sheet to 2nd sheet):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var range = source.getRange("A1:AS10");
  var destinationRange = destination.getRange("A1:AS10");

  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var fontSizes = range.getFontSizes();

  destinationRange.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
  destinationRange.setFontSizes(fontSizes);
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsizes

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontsizessizes

Comment: This is great. Thanks!